# ReactNative TextInput not letting me type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For both iOS and Android simulators

The text just disappears/flickers when I start typing. I tried having an initial state of texts with some value instead of keeping it empty. With this the TextInput sticks to this initial state and does not update itself with new text entered.

I think the state is not updating with 'onChangeText' property, but I am not completely sure.

People have seem to solve this, as they had few typos or missing pieces in code. However I have checked mine thoroughly.

Please help if I have missed anything in the below code.

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, CardSection, Input } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {

  state = { email: '', password: '' }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Email"
            placeHolder="user@gmail.com"
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })}
            value={this.state.email}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            secureTextEntry
            label="Password"
            placeHolder="password"
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })}
            value={this.state.password}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Button>
            Log In
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

**Input.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({ label, value, onChangeText, placeholder, secureTextEntry }) => {
  const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        autoCorrect={false}
        style={inputStyle}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  inputStyle: {
    color: '#000',
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 23,
    flex: 2
  },
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    flex: 1
  },
  containerStyle: {
    height: 40,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
};

export { Input };
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `onChangeText={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}` ?

Comment: sorry just noticed you are using `TextInput` from `react-native`

Comment: @Sagivb.g No problem. Let me know if the question has any misleading content or tags.

Comment: I would extract `onChangeText` to a class method and debug / log the changes, just to be sure you are getting back the proper value and be sure the problem is with the state not being updated

Comment: found your problem, your `Input` component is written in a wrong way. i'll explain with an answer

Comment: Still no luck :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to solve this was to change the way the values of TextInput fields are updated, with this code below.

```
value={this.state.email.value}
value={this.state.password.value}
```

Comment: Why does this work? I used to have `value={this.state.email}`  then added `.value` and it started to work. Does react-native add `.value` to each key in state or something? I've never had this problem with regular react

Answer (score 1):

You problem is how the `Input` component is written.
There is a `render` function written inside the stateless component which is not a React `class` component:

```
const Input = ({ label, value, onChangeText, placeHolder, secureTextEntry }) => ( // ← remove the wrapping parentheses 
  {
    render() { // <--- this should not be here
      ↑
      const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;
      return (
        <View style={containerStyle} >
          <Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Text>
          <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            autoCorrect={false}
            placeholder={placeHolder}
            style={inputStyle}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            value={value}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          />
        </View>
      );
    }

  }
);
```

Change it to this:

```
const Input = ({ label, value, onChangeText, placeHolder, secureTextEntry }) => {
  const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <View style={containerStyle} >
      <Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
        autoCorrect={false}
        placeholder={placeHolder}
        style={inputStyle}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={value}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**[See running example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/p7xxqzz3vx)**

Comment: Made changes as per your suggestion, however this did not work. The issue is still the same. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: odd, Your code is working for me in code sandbox. i will try to post a stack-snippet

Comment: I couldn't find a `react-native` cdn file, so i posted a link to a code sandbox project. You can see what are the difference with your code and the changes i made (though all the changes i made are posted in my answer)

Comment: Saw it in code sandbox project. Felt glad at least it works there.
Very strange that I am not able to achieve the same in my project. I did replace my code with your suggestion.

This is very weird

Comment: pay attention to the changes, removing the most outer parentheses `()` and removing the `render` and its curly braces `render{}`. when i ran your code as is, this was the only problem

Comment: Still no luck.. :|

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658623/unable-to-type-in-formik-field Could you have a look here please? onChangeText does not work me even though I am not using an explicit render() function within my TextInput